# Why posix_memalign function requires sizeof(void *) in alignment?

Tags: linux, c, posix, glibc

In the `posix_memalign()` man page, it is written that `alignment` argument should be `power of two and a multiple of sizeof(void *)`.

A similar program `memalign()` requires the `alignment` argument only to be `a power of two`.

Why `posix_memalign()` requires `alignment` argument to be a multiple of sizeof(void *) but the `memalign()` doen't ?

I went through the source code (specifically `glibc` implementation) of `posix_memalign()`, it internally calls the `memalign()` function. What is the difference between the two functions (except one is `posix` conformant and another is not) and why there is difference between the `alignment` variable requirement ?

Any technical explanation is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is down to historical reasons.

`memalign()` was introduced in SunOS, with the relaxed alignment requirements you describe, and these have been preserved [in the GNU C library](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memalign.3.html) (but not [in Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37843/memalign-3c.html)).

[`posix_memalign()` is part of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_memalign.html), and has stricter alignment requirements notably to ensure that the returned pointer can be used for direct block device I/O, and can be used to free the allocated memory with `free()`. Some implementations of `memalign()` don’t meet either of these requirements. See [the notes in the Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memalign.3.html#NOTES). Since POSIX specifies functions with wide applications (including platform coverage), the basic requirements need to be strong enough to not cause implementation difficulties on most platforms where one could want POSIX compliance.

`sizeof(void *)` is the platform’s pointer size, and that has historically been a common minimum alignment requirement in a variety of circumstances (including the two mentioned above).